# How do I make a list view of the days in each month in one activity depending on what month is clicked on in another activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

My android app displays a list of months upon opening it. When you click on a month, I want a list of the number of days to show up based on how many days are in each month. The problem I have is, I don't know how to get my MonthIntentChanger Activity to create the list of days in that month depending on what month is clicked on in my MainActivity. For example, if the user clicks on January, I want 1-31 to show up in a list so that they can click on the day, and for February I want to show a list from 1-28 to show, and so on. I want to do this in one activity. Previously I handled each month's list view of days in a separate activity which is inefficient. When the app starts, the months show up and when clicked they go to MonthIntentChanger but nothing shows up. Maybe this question is answered elsewhere, I did not see anything. What is in onthIntent was something I tried that did not workPlease let me know if something is unclear. Thanks

```
package com.example.android.hamptoneventsplanner;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class MonthIntentChanger extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.days_list_view);
        getIntent().getExtras();

    }


        /**
         *  Create a for loop that executes the following: Based on the number of days passed in, create
         *  that many numbers in listView.
         */

    public void getNumberOfDays(int days) {
        Integer[] day = new Integer[days];
        for (int daysInMonth = 0; daysInMonth <= day.length; daysInMonth++) {
            day[daysInMonth] = day[daysInMonth + 1];
        }

        ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, day);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rootView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}


package com.example.android.hamptoneventsplanner;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    int[] textViewIDs = new int[] {R.id.text_view1,R.id.text_view2,R.id.text_view3,
                                   R.id.text_view4,R.id.text_view5,R.id.text_view6,
                                   R.id.text_view7,R.id.text_view8,R.id.text_view9,
                                   R.id.text_view10,R.id.text_view11,R.id.text_view12};
    public int monthCounter = 12;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // For loop to iterate over the views, make them clickable, and fill them with the number of
        // days that they need
        for(int i = 0; i < monthCounter; i++) {
            // Iterate through the loop and find the text view for each month.
            TextView mainLabelView = (TextView)findViewById(textViewIDs[i]);
            // Set a clicklistener on that View
            mainLabelView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int monthCode = 0;
                    switch(view.getId()) {
                        case R.id.text_view1:
                            monthCode = 1;
                            break;
                        case R.id.text_view2:
                            monthCode = 2;
                            break;
                        case R.id.text_view3:
                            monthCode = 3;
                            break;
                        case R.id.text_view4:
                            monthCode = 4;
                            break;
                        case R.id.text_view5:
                            monthCode = 5;
                            break;
                        case R.id.text_view6:
                            monthCode = 6;
                            break;
                        case R.id.text_view7:
                            monthCode = 7;
                            break;
                        case R.id.text_view8:
                            monthCode = 8;
                            break;
                        case R.id.text_view9:
                            monthCode = 9;
                            break;
                        case R.id.text_view10:
                            monthCode = 10;
                            break;
                        case R.id.text_view11:
                            monthCode = 11;
                            break;
                        case R.id.text_view12:
                            monthCode = 12;
                            break;
                    }

                    //Create a new intent to open the activity to create the list views for each month
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MonthIntentChanger.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("monthCode",monthCode);
                    //Start the new activity
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent,monthCode);

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given what you are trying to do, it may be a lot simpler to use a CalendarView or a NumberPicker where you set the list of nunbers based on the month clicked. It would be a lot simpler and make a cleaner looking app. Much cleaner. Especially since you're basically making a calendar